# Valid characters for directory part of a URL (for short links)

Tags: http

Are there any other characters except A-Za-z0-9 that can be used to shorten links without getting into trouble? :)

I was thinking about +,;- or something.

Is there a defined standard regarding what characters can be used in a URL that browser vendors respect?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

A [path segment](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) (the parts in a path separated by `/`) in an absolute URI path can contain zero or more of *pchar* that is defined as follows:

```
  pchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
  pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

So it’s basically `A`–`Z`, `a`–`z`, `0`–`9`, `-`, `.`, `_`, `~`, `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `=`, `:`, `@`, as well as `%` that must be followed by two hexadecimal digits. Any other character/byte needs to be encoded using the [percent-encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).

Although these are 79 characters in total that can be used in a path segment literally, some user agents do encode some of these characters as well (e.g. `%7E` instead of `~`). That’s why many use just the 62 alphanumeric characters (i.e. `A`–`Z`, `a`–`z`, `0`–`9`) or the [Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) (i.e. `A`–`Z`, `a`–`z`, `0`–`9`, `-`, `_`).

Comment: @Joey: Not in a path segment as it’s the path segment delimiter.

Comment: Ok, I was kinda assuming the OP was talking about the whole path of an URI, not only a single segment. At least, URI shorteners usually work in the way of `http://domain.foo/<shortenedpart>` where it doesn't need to be restricted to a single sement.

Comment: So, it means that path part of URI can contain `&`, right? But this symbol is usually used as parameter delimiters in query part of URI.

Comment: @23W The query part of a URL *must* be introduced with `?`. Therefore, there is no ambiguity between `&` in the path and `&` in the query string.

Answer (score 46):

According to [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) the valid characters for the *path* component are:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 . - _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : @
```

as well as percent-encoded characters and of course, the slash `/`.

Keep in mind, though, that many applications (not necessarily browsers) that attempt to parse URIs to make them clickable, for example, may support a much smaller set of characters. This is akin to parsing e-mail addresses where most attempts also don't catch all addresses allowed by the standard.

Comment: Sorry - where are you referencing this, specifically in the spec? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-22 - I don't see any call-outs for character constraints on the path or segments.

Comment: @Jmoney38: See the definition of `pchar`.