# Bypassing query string validation (XSS prevention) in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, xss

I was performing a security assessment on a very old project that I'm assigned to, which uses ASP.NET WebForms. Basically, there were plenty of "Back" buttons placed around the site, which would redirect the user back to the previous page (based on a Return Url value).

The problem I found was that the button functionality was coded in JavaScript, with  tags around it, which meant that you could simply have something like ";alert('INSECURE!');" at the end of the return url and it would execute the script as soon as the button is clicked.

In order to sanitize that, validation was added - whenever the request contains a single quote ('), a double quote(") or <> symbols, an Invalid Request URL exception would be thrown. I'm fairly new to the security scene, so to me it sounds like a wonderful method.

Unfortunately, as I said I am a beginner when it comes to XSS prevention. Has anyone done anything similar and know of vulnerabilities in this approach? (And yes, I did my research. Spent several hours looking into different material and techniques, could not find anything similar and not too outdated though).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a wonderful method. Preventing all the various forms of XSS involves making sure that user-supplied content is appropriately neutered for every context into which it's injected - HTML, JavaScript, SQL, log files, whatever.

Comment: You might want to check out the [ASP.NET anti-XSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx) it was developed by people with a lot more knowledge of XSS who knew what they were doing in an ASP.NET context

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like you have URLs in the form `www.example.com/page.aspx?ReturnUrl=foo.aspx`

I tested this with the following JavaScript code

```
<a href="javascript:document.location = decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.substring(document.location.search.indexOf('ReturnUrl=') + 10));">Back</a>
```

and found while this worked for normal URLs and did not allow code to be appended such as `;alert('INSECURE!')`, you could still perform [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) by setting `ReturnUrl` to a JavaScript protocol URL such as `javascript:alert('foo')`. As the former worked in your project, it sounds like the code in your project is doing some sort of `eval` on the query string value, which is insecure in itself as eval should not be used on external input as an attacker can easily inject any code that they want in this input.

To prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) on your site you should perform some sort of validation on the `ReturnUrl` parameter. I would recommend the following.

- Code similar to the above should be used, where the `location` is set to the value rather than any sort of code evaluation happening on the query string.
- Validate the parameter to ensure that only relative URLs are allowed. This will also help guard your site against [Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards). An easy way would be to validate that the URL does not contain the "`:`" character, which will stop the protocol or domain being switched. E.g. this will prevent the protocol being changed from `http:`/`https:` to `javascript:` or anything else. [Technically this character is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669755/413180) in the path section of a URL, but it is extremely rare and if you know you are not using it in any page names on your site then this is a very good validation technique.
- Ditch the single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`) and angle bracket (`<>`) validation checks if you want, because you are now validating the URL to be relative, and your code is no longer `eval`uating.

In the above checks you could still throw your `Invalid Request URL exception` in the case of a failed validation.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a combination of Validation with a textbox filter to ensure that the data being entered is what you want it to be.

[Walkthrough: Validating User Input in a Web Forms Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw.aspx)

[FilteredTextBox Demonstration](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx)

Also, you could add captcha to your form.