# javascript regex function

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write JS regex (or function) that tells me if a string is in that format:

```
/root/:param1/:param2/:param3/.../
```

OR

```
/root/:param1/:param2/:param3/... (without last slash)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of your own?

Comment: Please provide more info. Right now it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Hint: you don't need a regular expression per se

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, it looks like we can break this pattern down into three primary components:

1. Start with `/root`
2. Followed by some number of `/:param`
3. Optionally followed by a `/`

Now we just need to develop the regular expressions for each component and combine them:

1. Start with `/root`

   - Start of the string is marked by `^` and we follow with `/root`
   - `^/root`
2. Followed by some number of `/:param`:

   - Let's say `:param` should match 1-N characters (`+` operator) that are not a forward slash `[^/]`
   - This gives us `/[^/]+`
   - 0-N of this entire unit can be matched using groups and the `*` operator: `(/[^/]+)*`
3. Optionally followed by a `/`

   - Use the `?` operator: `/?`
   - Append a `$` to specify the string's end

All together we get the regular expression `^/root(/[^/]+)*/?$`. You can use `RegExp.prototype.test` to check for matches:

```
r = new RegExp('^/root(/[^/]+)*/?$')
r.test('/root')                         // => true
r.test('/root/')                        // => true
r.test('/root/apple/banana')            // => true
r.test('/root/zebra/monkey/golf-cart/') // => true
```

If you're looking to match a URL path segment [you'll need to use a more specific character set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669755/390897) instead of the `[^/]` I used here for `:param` characters.