# Using dropwizard to make RESTful service, the URL can contain a space

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have some code making a `@Path` for an endpoint:

```
@Path("/productLine:[a-zA-Z]{1,25}}/cat")
```

I want to allow two word product lines in the URL.  I tried this

```
@Path("productLine:[a-zA-Z ]{1,25}}/cat")
```

But the client returns a

> HTTP 404 Not Found

when I use a request that has two words, like this:

```
/services/New Host/cat
```

Comment: A space is not a valid character in paths. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669692/valid-characters-for-directory-part-of-a-url-for-short-links - at server level, it's represented as `%20` and I guess, that's also what you have to specify in your `@Path()`. Browsers will often show a space instead, because it's nicer for the user. But they should send `%20` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

can u try with:

```
@Path("productLine:[a-zA-Z\x0B]{1,25}}/cat")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
@Path("productLine:[a-zA-Z%20]{1,25}}/cat")
```

The %20 is the HTTP encoding for space.