# How to properly encode Web API parameter in URL path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have endpoint used to find book by book reference.

The book reference is string that can contain white-space and any kind of special characters, e.g. `mybook`, `my book`, `my-book`, `my/book`, `book++`

```
// GET api/books/reference/{reference}
[HttpGet("reference/{reference}")]
public ActionResult<BookItem> FindByReference(string reference)
```

This is what I get when testing:

```
GET api/books/reference/mybook
OK

GET api/books/reference/my book
OK

GET api/books/reference/my-book
OK

GET api/books/reference/my+book
404 Not found

GET api/books/reference/my/book
404 Not found

GET api/books/reference/book++
404 Not found
```

What is a proper way to encode this `reference` parameter **IN THE URL PATH** so that it gets properly resolved by routing? Is that even possible?

Comment: The caller needs to properly escape those characters.

Comment: Thanks, but - weird - if I use `UrlEncode` on the `my book` I get the `my+book` which results in 404.

Comment: "api/books/reference/my book" seem to be wrong - I'd expect this to fail as space is not valid for path... As @JDB says the question is very strange - indeed Uri need to be constructed correctly first so testing invalid once is not really useful. Reading through RFC (or at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669692/valid-characters-for-directory-part-of-a-url-for-short-links) could help with "valid" definition.

Comment: You pass url as query parameter (since you've used UrlEncode)? That is even more confusing. Could you post some [MCVE] of your client side code and server side code that handles that query parameter to call your FindByReference method? (Normally one would use `new Uri("http://fooo/bar var").AbsoluteUri` for just url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding of the URLs is the responsibility of the client calling the API, a client must supply a valid URL if it wants a proper response. If you encode your examples you will get:

```
GET api/books/reference/mybook

GET api/books/reference/my%20book

GET api/books/reference/my-book

GET api/books/reference/my%2Bbook

GET api/books/reference/my%2Fbook

GET api/books/reference/book%2B%2B
```

These should now work.

If you want help with the actual encoding you will have to edit your question with the client source code.