# Validate that a given URL path is valid

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

How can I consider the following string as an invalid URL path because it actually contains a hostname and not represents a valid path:

```
/<>//google.com
```

---

By using the following regex validation code:

```
preg_match(""/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/"", $url, $matches);
```

I currently receive `true` for both:
`/<>//google.com` and `/3.2/`

while "/3.2/" is a legit URL path and not a domain name

Comment: url validation is hard.

Comment: why not use a url library instead of a regex?

Comment: @DanielA.White are you familiar with a good library API to validate it?

Comment: not off hand. i'm not a php dev.

Comment: To be fair, `google.com` *could* be part of a valid path, technically... there's nothing to stop you from having something like `www.mysite.com/sitemap/for/google.com` if you wanted.

Comment: let's take the following scenario: www.domain.com/google.com - How can I determine that google.com is not a "valid" path

Comment: The problem is that `www.domain.com/google.com` *could* be a valid URL (technically), so you'd need to cobble together something that parses the path component and rejects specific things; what *is* is about the string `google.com` that would make a path invalid but **not** `google.html` (for instance) or `google.womble` ? Technically they'd all be fine.

Comment: @CD001 agree that's a problem

Comment: you should use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: @drussey `parse_url` returns path part only: `/<>//google.com` which is not ok

Comment: @CD001 Wouldn't it make sense to count how many consequences forward-slashes there are? `/<>//google.com`  contains more than 2 consequences forward-slashes

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use FILTER_VALIDATE_URL and pass the FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED flag as well.

```
filter_var('http://host.com/path', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669755) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669750), I came up with something like this:

```php
function is_valid_url_path($url_path) {
  return preg_match("#^\/*[a-z0-9+&@=~_|!:,.;-]*\/*(%[0-9]([a-f]|[0-9]]))*/*$#i", $url_path);
}

print is_valid_url_path('/3.2/'); // 1
print is_valid_url_path('//3.2/'); // 1
print is_valid_url_path('/3.2///%3F'); // 1
print is_valid_url_path('/3.2///%3'); // 0
print is_valid_url_path("/<>//google.com"); // 0
```

Things I've considered within the regex:

- Allowed chars: `a-z A-Z 0-9 . - _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : @`
- [Percent-encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding): `DIGIT + (DIGIT | (A|B|C|D|E|F))` (e.g `%23`, `%3B`)
- A path contain multiple empty segments, e.g. `///hello//world`
- A path is terminated either with a `?`, `#` or simply by the end of the URI

Also see [RFC 3986, Sec. 3.3. Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).