# Slim v4 URL decode returns 404

Tags: php, slim

i am upgrading my application from slim v2 to v4

i have one route function menitoned below

```
$group->get('/get-data/{url}', '\V2:get_data');
```

when i pass the url variable a

```
api.app.com/get-data/xxxx%2fyyyyy
```

the route gives 404 ,

i tried with accessing the url in function with args but

```
function get_data($request,$response,$args){

  $slug =$args['url'];
  print_r($slug);die;

}
```

**but it doesn’t even entering into the function**

can anyone help with how we can pass the dynamic para with `%2f` in slim v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim uses fastroute as router. This is just a [known limitation with FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/issues/219).

The reason is, `%2f` is internally converted to `/`, and this is also a path segment delimiter. You may also notice a similar behavior with `%2e` which is just a `.` dot. But don't ask me why this happens with the dot.

URL path parameters should be more "simple", for example just a numeric value or just simple strings. That’s why many use just the 62 alphanumeric characters (i.e. A–Z, a–z, 0–9). [*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669755/1461181)

For more complex queries, a typical [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) might be more appropriate. This would then not affect the routing path.

If you want to use the Symfony router, check out this sample repo:
https://github.com/l0gicgate/slim4-symfony-router-exp

Comment: Thanks Odan i will try with query sting

Comment: Odan in fast route the only way to accept the url encode character is by query string right

Comment: @Dineshkarthik I don't understand your question. FastRoute is a library used by Slim under the hood. When you use a QueryString (`?param1=value1`) then FastRoute should not be affected.

Comment: if fast route we cannot able use `%2f` in url right  if we need to use the we need query string

Comment: Yes, for complexer queries, better use a HTTP QueryString.